# Calling a user defined function in EF - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5, user-defined-functions

I've declared a user defined function in SQL server.  Following the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847(v=vs.110).aspx) I refreshed the function into my EDMX (using "Update model from database"), which resulted in:

```
    <Function Name="uf_GradeToGradeFlag" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo" ReturnType="smallint">
      <Parameter Name="grade" Type="smallint" Mode="In" />
    </Function>
```

I then created a static method:

```
   [EdmFunction("SchoolManagement.BL", "uf_GradeToGradeFlag")]
    public static short GradeToGradeFlag(short grade)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
    }
```

Now, when I invoke this method in a Linq-to-Entities call, I get:

> System.NotSupportedException: The specified method 'Int16 GradeToGradeFlag(Int16)' on the type 'MyDomain.ModelDefinedFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.

I suspect the problem is with that `namespaceName` parameter in the [EdmFunctionAttribute constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.edmfunctionattribute.edmfunctionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).  But the documentation is very hazy.  What exactly is a "namespace", when you're talking about a SQL function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20709097/7850):

> The first attribute argument is the store namespace - you can find this in your edmx xml file on the Schema element (look for Namespace).