# Linq-to-Entities extension string concatenation

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this:

```
var query = (from u in entity.Users
             select new
                    {
                        FullName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
                    }
            );
```

Which works fine, but what I want to do is this:

```
var query = (from u in entity.Users
                select new
                {
                    FullName = u.FullName
                }
            );
```

I am using Metadata which returns `(u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName)`

```
[NotMapped]
public string FullName
{
    get
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error:

> The specified type member 'FullName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

I know that if I materialize the query it will work fine but I don’t want to do that. I want to do it at the db level, so what’s the best way of doing it, is it possible? Or I have to do this `(u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName)` all the time

p.s: I've also tried this: (not working for me)

```
public static Expression<Func<User, string>> FullName()
{
    return u => u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: if you use the model first approach you can create a UDF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131632/calling-a-sql-user-defined-function-in-a-linq-query

Comment: Expression approach should work. Can you show how you tried to use it?

Comment: if you fill the firstName and lastname the full name will be calculated when accessing the `FullName` property and your Fullname property is get only, how u set the value to that

Comment: What's your db ? Sql Server ? If yes, you could create a `Computed Column` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

Comment: @KasparsOzols: maybe i am not using it well, since i am not familiar with it, but i've tried this:  `FullName = u.FullName`

Comment: @Zulander : you need to replace the parameter to use your expression in a query. Take a look, for example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159697/replace-parameter-in-lambda-expression

Answer (score 1):

It won't work since db don't know how to execute your server-side method.
Possible options:

[Translation library:](https://github.com/damieng/Linq.Translations)

```
private static readonly CompiledExpression<Customer, string> fullNameExpression
   = DefaultTranslationOf<User>.Property(e => e.FullName)
                .Is(e => e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName);

[NotMapped]
public string FullName
{
     get { return fullNameExpression.Evaluate(this); }
}

var q = dbContext.Users.Select(u => new
     {
         FullName = u.FullName
     }).WithTranslations();
```

[DelegateDecompiler library:](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler)

```
[NotMapped]
[Computed]
public string FullName
{
     get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
}


var q = dbContext.Users.Select(u => new
     {
         FullName = u.FullName
     }).Decompile();
```

Encapsulation:

```
public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, MyDto>> SelectFullNames()
{
      return e => new MyDto{} { Fullname = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName; 
}

var queryable = dbConext.Users.Select(SelectFullNames());
```

Disclaimer - libraries no used in real-world-scenarions by me.