# EF 6.1 select scalar function result

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How to select database scalar function result as column using Entity Framework 6.1 Code First? This is pure SQL query:

```
SELECT
Id AS Id
, Name AS Name
, dbo.GetAdditionalInfo(Id) AS AdditionalInfo
FROM Users
WHERE Status = 1
```

Database function `dbo.GetAdditionalInfo(INT Id)` collects info from other tables and returns `VARCHAR` result. How to do that using EF 6.1? I need something like this:

```
var usersList = ctx.Users
.Where(n=>n.Status == 1)
.Select(n=>new{
    Id = n.Id
    , Name = n.Name
    , AdditionalInfo = ctx.DataBase.GetScalarFunctionResult<string>("dbo.GetAdditionalInfo (@)", n.Id)
}).ToList();
```

Of course,

```
ctx.DataBase.GetScalarFunctionResult<T>(string ScalarFunctionName, params object args)
```

doesn't exists and that's not working. But imho it could be very useful and easy to use, if implemented.

Comment: where is this function `GetScalarFunctionResult`? I can't find it. Is it something you've made? an extension method for `Database` property?

Comment: As I mentioned, function 'GetScalarFunctionResult' doesn't exists. I used it as an example to explain what I want to do. @kiziu suggested using external library (maybe it will work), but I don't like such methods. I used native SQL query, that works fine. Hope that future versions of EF will have support of calling sql functions.

Comment: How did you solve it? Any good way? I also have a similar problem,  sql like this: 
 select  id, dbo.fnDecrypt(seller, 'key123') as seller from table where dbo.fnDecrypt(seller, 'key123') like '%seller name%'

Comment: @Net205 Unfortunately, I didn't find easy solution, at this moment I continue using pure sql with manual data binding in some rare cases. As I now, DB functions are supported in EF Core 2.0+, but I didn't try that yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as shown below.

**Namespace :** `using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer`

```
 var usersList = ctx.Users
     .Where(n=>n.Status == 1)
     .Select(n=>new{
       Id = n.Id, Name = n.Name,
       AdditionalInfo = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>(yourQuery, parameters).FirstOrDefault() 
       }).ToList();
```

**Reference :** [**Execute Native SQL Query**](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: How will work your example? There will be the same AdditionalInfo in each object in list.I know, I can iterate through each element of List and fill AdditionalInfo by executing native SQL, but that will have performance issue. Real case is more complicated than I described in example.

Comment: Shows an error: " LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1[System.String] SqlQuery[String](System.String, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." Tried to replace calling function to simple "SELECT '1'" - doesn't work, too.

Comment: Namespace is present. It seems to me that EF doesn't support such subqueries.

Comment: did you try it without as a sub-query ? is that working then ?

Comment: Yes. If I comment line "AdditionalInfo = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>(yourQuery, parameters).FirstOrDefault()" all works fine

Comment: no,I mean can you run like this alone `ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>(yourQuery, parameters).FirstOrDefault()` ? what is the result ? is it working then ?

Comment: Very sorry for delayed reply. Yes, separate query works fine. Also, I tried to replace query to simple "SELECT 'sss'" (without calling func) - result is the same: separate query (var x = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>( "SELECT 'sss'").First();) works, but inside object initializer doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that what you want to achieve is described here [Entity Framework 6 Code First Custom Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517627/entity-framework-6-code-first-custom-functions). It will require an additional library, because it seems that EF6 does not support calling UDFs with Code-first out-of-the-box ([Calling a SQL User-defined function in a LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131632/calling-a-sql-user-defined-function-in-a-linq-query)).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (assuming the class inherits from DBContext):

```
String decryptedValue = String.Empty;
try {
   List<SqlParameter> parametros = new List<SqlParameter>();
   parametros.Add((new SqlParameter("@Data", value) { 
      SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary }));
   parametros.Add((new SqlParameter("@KeyValue", key) { 
      SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar }));

   String v = null;
   v = this.Database.SqlQuery<String>(
      "SELECT SEGURIDAD.FN_Get_DecryptionData(@Data,@KeyValue)", parametros.ToArray()).FirstOrDefault();
   decryptedValue = v;
} catch(Exception ex) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but question was how to use SQL function result as a column (property in returned object) in complicated LINQ query. Your example is calling pure sql and retrieving simple string result. I use similar method with pure sql, but there is no any benefits from entity framework. E.g. if I change function name, function parameters or switch to another DB type my solution compiles successfully without errors. I have to search by text and edit the text of sql query. That's acceptable, but not good.