# How to call an Sql User defined Function using Entity frame work Code first approach with LInq c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity frame work 6.0.0.0.I had an sql function which return 3 column
2 guid and one varchar (userid,ticketid,number).
but how to call this custom sql  function with out using ADO.net components.
AS Iam using entity frame work (code first approach).

Comment: If I'm not mistaking - Possible duplicate of [Calling a SQL User-defined function in a LINQ query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131632/calling-a-sql-user-defined-function-in-a-linq-query)

Comment: This might be closer: [Entity Framework 6 Code First Custom Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29517627/6400526)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I currently solve my problem by creating an SP to call that User defined SQL function and call that SP using c#  code.. But all i want to Know is that is there any elegent way of calling Userdefined  function that resides in the datatbase   using entityframe work(version 6.0.0.0) c# code...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same: a class derived from DbContext, with several DbSet properties and one stored procedure. I added three functions:

- Check if the stored procedure exists
- Create or Alter the stored procedure (needed in case of migration)
- Call the stored procedure.

Your question is about the last part. You might also want the other ones, so here are the three functions

```
public class InvoiceContext : DbContext
{
    // DbSet properties left out

    #region stored procedures
    private const string StoredProcedureNameProcessUsageCosts = "processusagecosts";

    public void CallStoredProcedureProcessUsageCosts(UsageCosts usageCosts)
    {
        object[] functionParameters = new object[]
        {
            new SqlParameter(@"ReportDate", usageCosts.ReportPeriod),
            new SqlParameter(@"CustomerContractId", usageCosts.CustomerContractId),
            new SqlParameter(@"CallType", usageCosts.CallType),
            new SqlParameter(@"TariffGroup", usageCosts.TariffGroup),
            new SqlParameter(@"VatValue", usageCosts.VatValue),
            new SqlParameter(@"PurchaseCosts", usageCosts.PurchaseCosts),
            new SqlParameter(@"RetailCosts", usageCosts.RetailCosts),
        };

        const string sqlCommand = @"Exec " + StoredProcedureNameProcessUsageCosts
            + " @ReportDate, @CustomerContractId, @CallType, @TariffGroup, @VatValue,"
            + " @PurchaseCosts, @RetailCosts";
        this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCommand, functionParameters);
    }

    public bool StoredProcedureProcessUsageCostsExists()
    {
        return this.Exists(StoredProcedureNameProcessUsageCosts);
    }

    public void CreateProcedureProcessUsageCosts(bool forceRecreate)
    {
        bool storedProcedureExists = this.Exists (StoredProcedureNameUpdateUsageCosts);

        // only create (or update) if not exists or if forceRecreate:
        if (!storedProcedureExists || forceRecreate)
        {   // create or alter:
            var x = new StringBuilder();

            // ALTER or CREATE?
            if (!storedProcedureExists)
            {
                x.Append(@"CREATE");
            }
            else
            {
                x.Append(@"ALTER");
            }

            // procedure name:
            x.Append(@" procedure ");
            x.AppendLine(StoredProcedureNameProcessUsageCosts);

            // parameters:
            x.AppendLine(@"@ReportPeriod int,");
            x.AppendLine(@"@CustomerContractId bigint,");
            x.AppendLine(@"@CallType nvarChar(80),");
            x.AppendLine(@"@TariffGroup nvarChar(80),");
            x.AppendLine(@"@VatValue decimal(18, 2),");
            x.AppendLine(@"@PurchaseCosts decimal(18, 2),");
            x.AppendLine(@"@RetailCosts decimal(18, 2)");

            // code
            x.AppendLine(@"as");
            x.AppendLine(@"begin");
            x.AppendLine(@"Merge [usagecosts]");
            x.AppendLine(@"Using (Select @ReportPeriod as reportperiod,");
            x.AppendLine(@"              @CustomerContractId as customercontractId,");
            x.AppendLine(@"              @CallType as calltype,");
            x.AppendLine(@"              @TariffGroup as tariffgroup,");
            x.AppendLine(@"              @VatValue as vatvalue)");
            x.AppendLine(@"              As tmp ");
            x.AppendLine(@"On ([usagecosts].[reportperiod] = tmp.reportperiod");
            x.AppendLine(@"AND [usagecosts].[customercontractId] = tmp.customercontractid");
            x.AppendLine(@"AND [usagecosts].[calltype] = tmp.calltype");
            x.AppendLine(@"AND [usagecosts].[tariffgroup] = tmp.tariffgroup");
            x.AppendLine(@"AND [usagecosts].[vatvalue] = tmp.Vatvalue)");
            x.AppendLine(@"When Matched Then ");
            x.AppendLine(@"    Update Set [usagecosts].[purchasecosts] = [usagecosts].[purchasecosts] + @purchasecosts,");
            x.AppendLine(@"               [usagecosts].[retailcosts] = [usagecosts].[retailcosts] + @retailcosts");
            x.AppendLine(@"When Not Matched Then");
            x.AppendLine(@"    Insert (ReportPeriod, CustomerContractId, calltype, tariffgroup, vatvalue, purchasecosts, retailcosts)");
            x.AppendLine(@"    Values (@reportPeriod, @CustomerContractId, @CallType, @TariffGroup, @VatValue, @PurchaseCosts, @RetailCosts);");
            x.AppendLine(@"end");
            this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(x.ToString());
        }
        // else: procedure exists and no forced recreate, nothing to do
    }
    #endregion stored procedures
}
```

Usage:

**Call the Stored Procedure**

```
using (var dbContext - new InvoiceContext(...))
{
    UsageCosts params = new UsageCosts()
    {
        ...
    };
    dbContext.CallStoredProcedureUsageCost(params);
}
```

**Create the stored procedure**

Do this for instance in [InitializeDataBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt136644(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges%601.InitializeDatabase(%600)) during initial seeding of the database, or in one of your migration functions

```
public override void InitializeDatabase(InvoiceContext context)
{
     // if not exists, create the stored procedure
     context.CreateProcedureProcessUsageCosts(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I currently solve my problem by creating an SP to call that User defined SQL function and call that SP using c#  code.. But all i want to Know is that is there any elegent way of calling Userdefined  function that resides in the datatbase   using entityframe work(version 6.0.0.0) c# code...

Comment: Well apparently there is an elegant way of calling a user defined function that resides in the database using EntityFramework. As I showed above, this is the function System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand which is accessible via DbContext.Database